# Hide connecton string of C# application in Web service

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, web-services

I had done many searches to check how to encrypt SQL connection string in app.config of C# application. I found that using aspnet_regiis is not secure as any one on the client machine can decrypt it if he know what to do, some advised to use web services, I could not find how, can any one give examples please?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

You need to build a layer between your client app and the SQL server. That's a recurring pattern in modern applications.

Create a web service that answers requests from the clients, fetching its data from the sql database. This way, the SQL connection string is never known by the client.